# Bluetooth Radio Device Is Not Available

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have hp pavilion g6-1302tx laptop.
I have a message in the "My Bluetooth" section of explorer stating "Bluetooth radio device is not available".
In device manager,there is no bluetooth device.
what shall i do for start bluetooth on my laptop.

Comment: Does the device appear in Devcie Manager without error?

Comment: Bluetooth hardware is not always installed on every model. This could be why you don't see it in Device Manager. Did your laptop have it when you purchased it? If so, have you turned it on?

Comment: I have this problem as well. Bluetooth will be working fine with my headset, and then after a largely varying amount of time, my bluetooth just crashes with no explanation and will not resume until I restart my computer.